# Embed TypeScript project into JS one

Tags: autocomplete, algolia, instantsearch

I have a laravel web site, which use Algolia InstantSerach.js for providing search functionality. Now I want to implement Autocomplete along with it.

In short: How can I translate this TypeScript library https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/charming-chandrasekhar-7t082 to JS files, which to use in my site?

Thanks!

I already tried to convert the files via tsc, but it does not work...